Second Derivative Test And Partials to prove $x^2 - xy + y^2 +yz + z^2 \geq 0$
Partial Derivatives
Treating the expression as a function $f(x,y) = x^2 - xy + y^2 +yz + z^2$ where z is constant
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x-y$
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y-x+z$
Setting the partials equal to zero and solving the system of equations I get, $x=-\frac{1}{3}z$ and $y=-\frac{2}{3}z$, for the location of the critical point
Second Partial Derivatives
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2} = 2$
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^2} = 2$
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial xy} = -1$
Second Derivative Test
$D = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2}(a,b) \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^2}(a,b) - [\frac{\partial f}{\partial xy}(a,b)]^2 = (2)(2)-(-1)^2 = 3$
$D > 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2}(a,b) > 0$ so the critical point/s at $(-\frac{1}{3}z, -\frac{2}{3}z)$ is/are a minimum.
Question
Is this sufficient to prove $x^2 - xy + y^2 +yz + z^2 \geq 0$ ? Should I also mention that the output at the critical point/s $f(-\frac{1}{3}z, -\frac{2}{3}z) = \frac{2}{3}z^2$

$x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$

FYI, a simple way to prove that $x^2-xy+y^2+yz+z^2\ge 0$ is to note that $2(x^2-xy+y^2+yz+z^2)=x^2+(x^2-2xy+y^2)+(y^2+2yz+z^2)+z^2=x^2+(x-y)^2+(y+z)^2+z^2$

No, it is possible for a function to have a single local min/max and have a different global min/max. However, it is true for your function. This is because $D>0$ and $f_{xx}>0$ everywhere. A smooth function that satisfies this is a strictly convex function. It happens to be the case that for convex functions, local minima are unique and are also global minima. This means that $f \geq 0$ and, furthermore, $f(x,y) > 0$ when $(x,y)$ is not a critical point.

Side note: demanding integer values for $x,y,z$  and letting those vary freely, we represent all odd numbers and most even numbers. It represents all positive integers other than these: $ \;4^k \, (16 n - 2) \; . \; \; \;$
Taking the Hessian matrix of your quadratic form;  by Sylvester's Law of Inertia, $H$  is positive definite, it can only be zero when $x,y,z$  are all zero.
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

wow that's interesting, thanks for sharing!

Just another possible approach for the sake of curiosity:
\begin{align*}
x^{2} - xy + y^{2} + yz + z^{2} & = \left(x^{2} - xy + \frac{y^{2}}{4}\right) + \frac{y^{2}}{2} + \left(\frac{y^{2}}{4} + yz + z^{2}\right)\\\\
& = \left(x - \frac{y}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{y^{2}}{2} + \left(\frac{y}{2} + z\right)^{2} \geq0
\end{align*}

definitely more concise!
